# Multiple RewriteRule in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?$1=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?$1=1 [L]

#if category 
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?results=true&lid=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?results=true&lid=$1 [L,NC]
```

the first section works just fine, when i add category in url, it writes category before the other parameters everywhere, so css and images are being disappeared.

mywebsite.com/category/380 should redirect to  mywebsite.com/index.php?results=true&lid=380 which does but the original url has pics and css but the clean url doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the relative base URI has changed and your css and images were probably relative links (e.g. `<img src="image_folder/image.png">`) as opposed to absolute (e.g. `<img src="/image_folder/image.png">`).

The original base was `/`, which is where `index.php` sat. But once you have `/category/something`, the base became `/category/`. So you can either change all your links from relative to absolute (by adding a leading slash), or you can add this in the header of all your pages:

```
<base href="/">
```

---

If the links to css and images are already being generated with a `/category/` in front of the URI, then that sounds like something related to your framework. But if there's no fix for that, you can add these rules above the ones you already have:

```
# if the request ends with one of these extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|png|gif|jpe?g|bmp|ico|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

Comment: <base href="/"> works but only for front page, when i enter /category/something, the header file is still the same in source it shows the base tag but all inside url's have /category before the real url

Comment: @Mr.Crowley How are you generating these pages? They're being generated **with** `/category/` in front already? - I've edited my answer

Comment: the pages are generating in a loop from mysql. and no they don't have category prefix while generating but after the page with clean url loads all links have category before them. It looks like the rewriteRule repeats it self... i don't know, i'm stuck

Comment: i also tested your rewriteCond, nothing changed but it took so song to load clean urls. im sure the rule rewrites itself again.

Comment: @Mr.Crowley If the rule looped, you'd get a 500 error. When I tested it, there wasn't any looping.

Comment: i think its because of the sub folder. the real url is website.com/2012/index.php and so it becomes website.com/2012/category/12 and thats when the unwanted category word appears in url. i guess i can't do anything because the website is old written without even .htaccess and of course no clean urls. can you think of something doable ?

Comment: @Mr.Crowley without knowing why a `/category/` magically appears out of thin air, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: after i add `#RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?results=true&lid=$1 [L,NC]` into htaccess, when i write lets say, `website.com/2012/category/12` all inner links will add up with `/category/`. it surely is not from php code.

Comment: @Mr.Crowley That rule won't even match an image. It ends with a `/` and doesn't allow for any extension. It's not the rules that you have that's adding the category, those rules only **remove** the category.

Comment: you need to see for yourself. this is the [link](http://www.canddvisionaryinc.com) just try the rules and you will see.

Comment: @Mr.Crowley When I go to [this link](http://www.canddvisionaryinc.com/cd2012/category/536), and look at the page source, I see `<base href="cd2012">` in the header, which is wrong. It needs to say `<base href="/cd2012/">`

Comment: what a shame ! thanks a lot i really appreciate your help. nice job on Jerminal by the way its cool to have your own terminal :)

Comment: @Mr.Crowley glad it was something simple and not something esoteric or nasty. Jerminal is so old! I don't think I've looked at that stuff for 10+ years